# How do i add "", to a list of names?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a long list (about 2000 names). It would take forever if i was going to put commas and quotation marks on all of them. Therefore I would like to make a list.
The names are in a python filed named def_names.py
I already have them all like this:

```
Name1 
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
```

But I want to add "", to the names.
So the final result would look like this:

```
list = [
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3",
    "Name4",
    "Name5",
]
```

This is so i can make a list. How do I do that?

I need this list for another py script which uses those names as part of a name database.
I am using PyCharm if that matters.

Comment: escape character (\) or use single quotes

Comment: Hold on - where exactly is the starting text? Do you want to read it from a plain .txt file, or are you trying to put it directly into your .py file? Or exactly what? Back up and explain the *entire* problem, including the purpose of the list you're going to make.

Comment: Karl the names are in a py file. I need the list for another py file...

Answer (score 2):

Depending how the list of names is, you could do something like this:

```
names = "name1,name2,name3,name4,name5"

name_list = names.split(',')
print(name_list)

>>> ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
```

EDIT: Using the new example you posted I assume you have these in a file, in that case you could do;

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
  names_list = [name.strip() for name in f.readlines()]

print(names_list) 


>>> ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5']
```